# How can I rotate an object already at an angle?

Tags: transforms

I can't seem to figure out which setting to use for proper hand rotation. It starts out like:

[image]

And no matter what XYZ settings I choose, I end up with a result similar to:

[image]

...instead of a nice circular rotation in the socket. (The hand is a child of the arm, which is a child of the torso, if that makes any difference.)
If anyone knows what the settings should be, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Hit R then Z and again Z.

Comment: Or use the manipulation handles - click the arc icon (second to the right of 'Local' in the tool bar at the bottom of the 3d view) then use the rotation handles to rotate around the local axes.

Comment: Another option would be to click the Lock icons alongside the rotation properties for X and Y in the properties panel. This will prevent manipulation of those rotation values so that it will only be able to be rotated around Z.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Rich Sedman; locking the X and Y helped this time around, as well as adjusting the 3D cursor to further up the elbow.